# Polling AWS SQS Events using a ECS Service in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to create a ECS Service using Java that will do long polling of SQS for events.

By using ReceiveMessageRequest class in AWS SDK I can set WaitTimeSeconds to 20s after which when it returns a empty list of messages. But how can I keep on continuously monitoring the events from the queue.

Comment: By sending a new request after the first one comes back. And doing that over and over and over again in a `while` loop.

Comment: @luk2302 Thought so.